# Excel Formula to JavaScript Conversion

Tags: javascript, excel, formula

I have the following formula in Excel

```
=1-(B30^(EXP(D30-C30)))
```

where B30, D30 and C30 are cells.

I am converting it into JavaScript something like this

```
result = 1 - (Math.pow(Math.exp(D30-C30), B30));
console.log(result);
```

The result is different in JavaScript output, with the exact same input values. If anyone please pointout what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`base` in `Math.pow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow) should be the first argument:

```
result = 1 - (Math.pow(B30, Math.exp(D30-C30)));
```